# How to create multiple dictionaries and search them in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to write a program using dictionaries that will allow the user to enter a course and section number which then returns the information about the course. For example if the user enters 10851_01L it the program should return: "The course is MIS113 with Professor Beaudry locate in OW206"
This is the following code I am using. Upon running the program I am getting a KeyError for the class that the CRN_SEC number was entered for.

```
def main():
    course = create_course()
    instructor = create_instructor()
    location = create_location()
    search = input('Please enter a CRN and section Key, input must be formatted as CRN_SEC: ')
    value = course[search]
    print(instructor[value])
    print(location[value])
def create_course():
    return {'10193_01W':'MIS102', '10227_01W':'MIS103', '10850_01':'MIS113', 
    '10851_01L':'MIS113', '10511_01':'MIS118', '10512_01L':'MIS118', '11263_01W':'MIS145', 
    '10780_01W':'MIS206', '11015_01W':'MIS251', '10385_01':'MIS255', '10513_01W':'MIS273', 
    '10514_01L':'MIS273', '11479_01W':'MIS275', '11934_01W':'MIS285', '10325_01':'MIS311', 
    '10333_01W':'MIS311', '10596_01W':'MIS322', '11797_01W':'MIS341', '11480_01W':'MIS344', 
    '11129_01W':'MIS407', '11964_02W':'MIS407', '10809_01W':'MIS442', '10852_01':'MIS496'}
def create_instructor():
    return {'10193_01W':'Huntley', '10227_01W':'Huntley', '10850_01':'Beaudry', 
    '10851_01L':'Beaudry', '10511_01':'MacDougal', '10512_01L':'MacDougal', '11263_01W':'Carrere', 
    '10780_01W':'Kirby', '11015_01W':'Coon', '10385_01':'Dickson', '10513_01W':'MacDougal', 
    '10514_01L':'MacDougal', '11479_01W':'Stewart', '11934_01W':'Dickson', '10325_01':'Coon', 
    '10333_01W':'Kirby', '10596_01W':'Kirby', '11797_01W':'Stewart', '11480_01W':'Dickson', 
    '11129_01W':'Stewart', '11964_02W':'Stewart', '10809_01W':'Dickson', '10852_01':'Dickson'}
def create_location():
    return {'10193_01W':'Web', '10227_01W':'Web', '10850_01':'OW206', '10851_01L':'OW206',
    '10511_01':'BH124', '10512_01L':'OW206', '11263_01W':'Web', '10780_01W':'Web', 
    '11015_01W':'Web', '10385_01':'OW223', '10513_01W':'OW112', '10514_01L':'OW112', 
    '11479_01W':'Web', '11934_01W':'Web', '10325_01':'OW216', '10333_01W':'Web',
    '10596_01W':'Web', '11797_01W':'Web', '11480_01W':'Web', '11129_01W':'Web',
    '11964_02W':'Web', '10809_01W':'Web', '10852_01':'OW123'}    
main()
```

Comment: What happens when just do a `print(instructor[search])` and `print(location[search])` instead? It seems like you're translating your search key to a value and try to access instructor and location with the value instead of the key.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, it is the `KeyError`. This means, the supplied Key is not available in the `dict` instance.

In your following section of logic, the input value is captured in `search (eg: 10851_01L)` and is then looked-up  agonist `course` dict; and return `value (eg: MIS113)` is further looked-up in `instructor` dict . However, the `instructor` dict doesn't have any key under `MIS113`. This is a logical error from your side and can be corrected if you follow what I'm try to say.

```
search = input('Please enter a CRN and section Key, input must be formatted as CRN_SEC: ')
value = course[search]
print(instructor[search])
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you are placing this in three different dictionaries? Why not just do something like:

```
my_dict = {
      "10193_01W": {
          "course": "MIS102",
          "instructor": "Huntley", 
          "location": "Web"
        },
        ...
    }
```

And then simplify just fetch `my_dict["10193_01W"]["course"]` for example to get the course number